# Javascript code to separate even and odd numbers then get their respective sums and averages

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this code that requires a user to specify the length of an array,store some values in the  array then separate the odd and even numbers. I have done everything so far but i am getting some incorrect output. I have attached my code.

```js
//Variable and array declaration
var arrayNum = []; //Create an array with no size
var arrayEven = []; //Array to hold even numbers
var arrayOdd = []; //Array to hold odd numbers
var i; //Variable to store the index of arrayNum() above
var NUM_INPUTS; //Variable to store array size which is the number of elements
var sumOdd = 0.0; //variable to store the sum if the odd numbers
var sumEven = 0.0; //variable to store the sum if the odd numbers
var avgO = 0.0;
var avgE = 0.0;

NUM_INPUTS = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of inputs you need: ")); //Ask the user to specify size of the array
//loop for entering values into the array
for (i = 0; i < NUM_INPUTS; i++) {
  arrayNum.push(parseFloat(prompt("Enter the numbers: " + (i + 1))));
  //Check whether a number is odd and add it to arrayOdd[]
  if ((arrayNum[i] % 2) === 1) {
    arrayOdd.push(arrayNum[i]);
    for (var x = 0; x < arrayOdd.length; x++) {
      sumOdd += arrayOdd[x];
    }
    //calculate the sum of odd numers
    avgO = sumOdd / arrayOdd.length;
  }
  //Check whether a number is eve and add it to arrayEven[]
  else {
    arrayEven.push(arrayNum[i]);
    for (var y = 0; y < arrayOdd.length; y++) {
      sumEven += arrayEven[y];
    }
    //sumEven+=arrayEven[i]; //calculate sum of even numbers
    avgE = sumEven / arrayEven.length;
  }
}

//Output results
document.write("All numbers in the array are: " + arrayNum);

document.write("<br/>All even numbers in the array are: " + arrayEven);
document.write("<br/> The sum of all even numbers is: " + sumEven + " and average of the even numbers is: " + avgE);

document.write("<br/>");
document.write("<br/>All odd numbers in the array are: " + arrayOdd);
document.write("<br/> The sum of all odd numbers is: " + sumOdd + " and the average of the odd numbers is " + avgO);
```

Comment: You should sum up the even and odds after you collected all numbers.

Comment: I believe I have done that to the best of my knowledge. check the for loop after inserting the elements into their respective arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing following things wrong

- You are adding all the previous values of `arrayOdd` and `arrayEven` again and again. You should add the new value to the `sumOdd` and `sumEven`.
- You are calculating average before all inputs are completed. You should calculate `avgO` and `avgE` at end of loop.

```js
var arrayNum = [];
var arrayEven = []; 
var arrayOdd = []; 
var i; 
var NUM_INPUTS;  
var sumOdd = 0.0;
var sumEven = 0.0; 
var avgO = 0.0;
var avgE = 0.0;

NUM_INPUTS = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of inputs you need: "));
for (i = 0; i < NUM_INPUTS; i++) {
  arrayNum.push(parseFloat(prompt("Enter the numbers: " + (i + 1))));
  if ((arrayNum[i] % 2) === 1) {
    arrayOdd.push(arrayNum[i]);
    sumOdd += arrayNum[i];
  }
  else {
    arrayEven.push(arrayNum[i]);
    sumEven += arrayNum[i];
    
  }
}
avgO = sumOdd / arrayOdd.length;
avgE = sumEven / arrayEven.length;
//Output results
document.write("All numbers in the array are: " + arrayNum);

document.write("<br/>All even numbers in the array are: " + arrayEven);
document.write("<br/> The sum of all even numbers is: " + sumEven + " and average of the even numbers is: " + avgE);

document.write("<br/>");
document.write("<br/>All odd numbers in the array are: " + arrayOdd);
document.write("<br/> The sum of all odd numbers is: " + sumOdd + " and the average of the odd numbers is " + avgO);
```

Comment: OMG!!! Such a dumb mistake but thanks man. I realized where I was making the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, explain your code to a duck! 
(No I'm not kidding, this is known as *rubber duck debugging*)

The user enters 2 as the count of numbers he wants to insert.

The loop will iterate 2 times and ask the user for a number.

The user enters 1 as the first number.

1 is odd, therefore it gets pushed to `arrayOdd`, it also gets added to `sumOdd` which is `1` then.

The user enters 3 as the second number. As it is odd, it will also get pushed into `arrayOdd`. The inner loop runs again, iterates over `arrayOdd`, takes the first element (`1`) and adds it to `sumOdd` (!), which is 2 now, then it takes the second element (`3`) and adds it to `sumOdd`, `sumOdd` is 5.

*But wait ... the sum of 1 and 3 is 4, not 5. Summing up all numbers of `sumOdd` and `sumEven` in the loop seems to be a mistake.*

```
 for (var x = 0; x < arrayOdd.length; x++) {
  sumOdd += arrayOdd[x];
}
```

That has to be:

```
 sumOdd += /* left as an exercise */;
```

Comment: rubber duck debugging ftw

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I found is that you use oddnum arrays for calculating even numbers.

```
for (var y = 0; y < arrayOdd.length; y++) {
      sumEven += arrayEven[y];
    }
```

```js
//Variable and array declaration
var arrayNum = []; //Create an array with no size
var arrayEven = []; //Array to hold even numbers
var arrayOdd = []; //Array to hold odd numbers
var i; //Variable to store the index of arrayNum() above
var NUM_INPUTS; //Variable to store array size which is the number of elements
var sumOdd = 0.0; //variable to store the sum if the odd numbers
var sumEven = 0.0; //variable to store the sum if the odd numbers
var avgO = 0.0;
var avgE = 0.0;

NUM_INPUTS = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of inputs you need: ")); //Ask the user to specify size of the array
//loop for entering values into the array
for (i = 0; i < NUM_INPUTS; i++) {
  arrayNum.push(parseFloat(prompt("Enter the numbers: " + (i + 1))));
  //Check whether a number is odd and add it to arrayOdd[]
  if ((arrayNum[i] % 2) === 1) {
    arrayOdd.push(arrayNum[i]);
    for (var x = 0; x < arrayOdd.length; x++) {
      sumOdd += arrayOdd[x];
    }
    //calculate the sum of odd numers
    avgO = sumOdd / arrayOdd.length;
  }
  //Check whether a number is eve and add it to arrayEven[]
  else {
    arrayEven.push(arrayNum[i]);
    for (var y = 0; y < arrayEven.length; y++) {
      sumEven += arrayEven[y];
    }
    //sumEven+=arrayEven[i]; //calculate sum of even numbers
    avgE = sumEven / arrayEven.length;
  }
}

//Output results
document.write("All numbers in the array are: " + arrayNum);

document.write("<br/>All even numbers in the array are: " + arrayEven);
document.write("<br/> The sum of all even numbers is: " + sumEven + " and average of the even numbers is: " + avgE);

document.write("<br/>");
document.write("<br/>All odd numbers in the array are: " + arrayOdd);
document.write("<br/> The sum of all odd numbers is: " + sumOdd + " and the average of the odd numbers is " + avgO)
```